# 1 запрос с 4мя JOIN или 4 запроса?

Tags: php, sql

Есть запрос такой

```
SELECT t.id AS `t_id`, t.title AS `t_title`, t.status AS `t_status`,
        u.login AS `u_login`, a.login AS `a_login`
        FROM `tickets` t 
        LEFT JOIN `users` u ON u.id = t.creator_id
        LEFT JOIN `ticket_msgs` tm ON tm.ticket_id = t.id
        LEFT JOIN `users_admin` a ON a.id = tm.admin_id
        WHERE t.creator_id = :creator_id
```

И вот задумался над вопросом, может лучше использовать вместо этого одного запроса, 4 запроса?.. Просто разбив этот запрос на 4 части.

```
SELECT t.id AS `t_id`, t.title AS `t_title`, t.status AS `t_status`
FROM `tickets` t
WHERE t.creator_id = :creator_id;

SELECT login FROM users WHERE id = $query_1_res->creator_id;

И остальные 2...
```

Есть ли смысл так делать? Просто человек посмотрел, сказал запрос очень тяжелый, и стоит разбить на несколько запросов.

Индексы расставлены в таблицах по `id`.

Comment: Как он определил, что запрос тяжелый. Если индексы есть, ничего тяжелого в нем быть не должно (можно конечно план выполнения посмотреть). А 4 отдельные запроса обычно гораздо медленнее, потому как каждый их них должен быть еще разобран СУБД плюс накладные расходы дравера на передачу

Comment: Вот и я засомневался, ибо 4 запроса в любом случае дольше у меня отрабатывают..

Comment: А точно ли нужен LEFT джойн? Допускает ли логика отсутствия записей в связанных таблицах?

Comment: нет, записи должны быть в таблицах.

Comment: проверте с помощью explain скорость выполнения в обеих случаях...

Comment: я так понимаю, что формально мысль ревьювера была такая, что незачем в общий набор данных N-раз выбирать данные из `users`, т.к. там всегда одно и то же будет? В целом если выборка большая, то может это и имеет смысл. В целом если у нас куча тикетов, и куча сообщений в них, то смысла особого все это перемножать и тащить все целиком тоже особого нет. Запрос может и не "тяжелый" просто нелогично вытаскивать все сразу в одной куче.

Comment: Вот что дал explain
http://joxi.ru/vAWYXZ1FeZ6emW